# How to pronounce "scorpion'll", "Jim'll", etc

Tags: pronunciation

I was talking to someone about a fight between a scorpion and a beetle before we watch the actual video. We were predicting what would happen.

I wanted to sound informal by saying, *"the scorpion **'ll kill** the beetle"*. Then suddenly it came to me it would sound wierd (like Lionel) and I wasn't sure how it should be said so I chose the safer choice and  said, *"the scorpion **will kill** the beetle"*.

I know native speakers have no problem saying it and as I checked the possible duplicates, it's actually quite common though there wasn't any question saying how to actually say it.

Long story short, I want the phonetic transcript of *"scorpion'll"*. Should I add ***schwa*** after **n**? i.e. /ˈskɔːpiən**ə**l/. And for a rule of thumb should I do the same with all other consonant sounds?  For examlpe, *Jim'll, Vladimir'll*.

Comment: Yes, you do need a **schwa**. English pronunciation is so random anyway that most english speakers don't even realise when they use a schwa. In languages with more rigid pronunciation rules, like arabic, you need to understand when a schwa is necessary. For arabic, you insert one if putting two words together results in a sequence of three or more consonants. Probably by coincidence, it works exactly like that in the consonant + 'll situation.

Comment: You're right that you generally can't use this construction for anyone whose name already ends in an 'L' (e.g. Lionel).  I'd also avoid it when there's possibility of confusion with such a name, e.g. "The lion'll attack Lionel if he gets too close."

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Note that even if it'd be ambiguous or hard to detect perfectly, I think that many speakers wouldn't hesitate to actually say "Lionel'll go to the store." It does sound a little funny if you listen carefully, but "Bill'll go to the store" seems plausible.

Comment: *"Shake and shake / The catsup bottle. / None'll come- / And then a lot'll"* - [Richard Armour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Armour)

Comment: For what it's worth, there was a famous TV show called "Jim'll Fix It", which suggests that that particular contraction is acceptable.

Comment: The way American English is evolving, pretty soon schwa will be the only vowel sound we use.

Comment: @TRiG - About the only thing still acceptable in relation to that show.

Comment: A little like the site name: ***ull***

Comment: yes, a schwa, but a schwa can sound different depending on its environment,like any other 'letter'.

Comment: @JavaLatte I don't see why you need a schwa.  You can certainly have a syllabic liquid.  You might argue that a syllabic liquid is underlyingly a phonological schwa + liquid sequence which can be (in this case) realized phonetically with or without schwa, but that's a matter of theory and probably not terribly useful to learners.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's either a syllabic /l̩/ or /əl/.

These are allophones in English, which means there is no phonemic difference between them—it never changes the meaning. Which one you use depends on which dialect you speak, and maybe also on the consonant before it.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/little) uses the rule: use /l̩/ after /t/, /d/, and /n/ (as in *little*, *saddle*, and *panel*) and /əl/ after other consonants (as in *pickle*). While some Americans may follow this rule, I don't—I use /l̩/ after /t/ and /k/, but I use /əl/ after /n/. Unless you're trying to speak exactly like a native speaker, feel free to use whichever is easier for you.

Answer (score 9):

I think you've got the right idea; use the *'ll* as though you were forming a more standard contraction, such as *I'll, he'll*, or *we'll*.

There's plenty of precedent for doing it that way, from this book published almost a century ago:

> “It's a biggish hole, but Jim'll be all right in a few days, never fear.”
>   <sub>Source: *Jim: The Story of a Backwoods Police Dog* by Sir Charles G. D. Roberts, 1919</sub>

to this story published just a few years ago:

> “You go find Aunt Bess. Me and Bert and Jim'll do the family's share of the fightin'.”
>   <sub>Source: *The Pumpkin Rollers* by Elmer Kelton, 2011</sub>

As for pronunciation, why not simply mimic what the dictionaries say for other contractions?

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/they-ll) and [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/they-ll?a=british) show **ðeɪl** for *they'll*, for example.

For words like *scorpion'll* and *Jim'll*, try looking at words that end with a similar end sound, such as [funnel](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/funnel) (ˈfʌnəl) and [camel](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/camel) (ˈkæməl).

Comment: Thanks, just a point to clarify, by _"you've got the right idea"_ you're suggesting my generalization about using _**schwa**_ is right?

Comment: Ah, Yuri, you had to ask me the hard question! :-) I think so; the exact sound might vary a little bit based on the last syllable and consonant, so _scorpion'll_ would be phonetically similar to, say, _funnel_, which is depicted with a [schwa](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/funnel). I edited my question to explain that more clearly.

Comment: Thanks... BTW the beetle actually got to kill the scorpion! That was a bummer ;)

Comment: **they'll** is slightly different as **they** ends in a vowel sound. [**it'll**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-ll) shows the more usual case which Cambridge places somewhere between a syllabic 'l' and schwa plus 'l'.

Comment: @user52889: I interpret Cambridge's IPA as *either* a syllabic 'l' or a schwa plus 'l'. And that's what [their key](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/help/phonetics.html#consonants) says, as well. You don't need to worry about how to pronounce some sound halfway between them.

Comment: Yes, you're quite correct, the guide says clearly that either pronunciation is acceptable, and I should have made that clearer in my comment. In practice in these cases the expression will fall somewhere between these two extremes, and I believe the intention of the superscript schwa is to convey the range of acceptable expressions; in any case you're right to say you needn't worry.

Answer (score 6):

It a syllabic l, which is perceptually close to, but not identical to, a schwa followed by an l.

Here is a podcast where the syllabic l is pronounced:

http://www.pronuncian.com/podcasts/episode142

So "it'll" rhymes with "little." "That'll" rhymes with "Seattle" or "battle," etc.

edit: thought of an old rhyme from the Simpsons... "some folk'll never eat a skunk, but then again, some folk'll... like Cletus, the slack-jawed yokel." (This is funny but not an accurate example, since in fact "will" doesn't normally contract to 'll when the verb isn't explicitly given afterwards.)

Answer (score 2):

You would simply add the sound of "uhl" in American English; i.e., Scopionuhl, Jimuhl, etc. (It's a short "u" sound, either with your tongue down and its tip behind your lower teeth or on the palate right behind the upper teeth.) Also, as Adam noted in his comment, it is never stressed.

Comment: ...and it is _never_ stressed.  (BTW - I put the tip of my tongue behind my upper teeth right at the end)

Comment: @Mark Hubbard Just to make sure I got it right: you're taking about the same middle sound in _book_, i.e. **/ʊ/**? So this would be the transcript: /ˈskɔːpiən**ʊ**l/, and not /ˈskɔːpiənəl/.

Comment: Thanks, @Adam, good point. Tongue touching the upper palate right behind the teeth works for me too. I've edited my answer accordingly and changed "ull" to "uhl" to make it more clear that it is not like "book."

Comment: @Yuri: It is a syllabic /l/ sound. For me, it is approximately the same sound in "full," which is generally transcribed as /fʊl/. But even though "full" is  considered to have the "same" vowel sound as the one in "book," the pronunciation is affected by the following /l/. For me, there is no difference between fully unstressed /ʊl/, /əl/ and /l̩/. But this may differ for other speakers.

Comment: What you are describing is a schwa, as @Yuri suggested. http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000383.htm